# C - How to read multiple arguments in getopts?

Tags: c, arguments

I created a C file and It works correctly when handling one argument. How may I pull the multiple arguments in getopts?

Single Argument is running fine :

```
test -c 3 -t 1101  -i 1S
```

I want to read multiple arguments like this :

```
test -c 3 -t 1101 1102 1103 -i 1S
```

Below is the code for getops:

```
   struct option long_options[] =
   {
      {"testCase", required_argument, 0, 't'},
      {"interval", required_argument, 0, 'i'},
      {"cell", required_argument, 0, 'c'},
      {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
      {0, 0, 0, 0}
   };
   optind = 0;
   while (1)
   {
      int option_index = 0;
      z = getopt_long(argc, argv, ":t:i:c:", long_options, &option_index)
      
      ...
```

Comment: As far as I know, getopt doesn't do that. It just doesn't. Sorry.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) and the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ? If on Linux, read [getopt(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: Is there a  way i can do this apart from Getops..?. i want dependency on c (c1,c2,c3)

Comment: Yes, but you do need to spend hours in reading documentation. **Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* open source programs**, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/). Show some [mre] with your `main`

Comment: It looks like you want to have an option that takes multiple arguments.  This is not supported by any version of `getopt()` I know, including GNU's very capable one.  It's difficult to see how it would be supported, because allowing one option to accept more than one argument makes argument parsing ambiguous.

Comment: What you can do instead is accept an option argument with internal structure, such as comma-separated sub-arguments.  You can see this approach in use in certain utilities.  In this case, you get the one, combined argument from `getopt()`, then parse out the pieces yourself.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger i want to read multiple arguments.. How may I do this if i dont use getopt?

Comment: @AndleebHasan, you can do whatever custom analysis you want on `argv`.  If you have a program-specific way to recognize multiple arguments to the same option then code away!  But I don't think you'll find *any* function for the purpose available from a pre-built library.

Comment: You can allow several `t` argument `test -c 3 -t 1101 -t 1102 -t 1103 -i 1S` but a list with comma as separator seems better

Comment: Hi @Ôrel - Thanks for your reply but I need dependency on '-c' .... like c1 goes to 1101, c2 goes to 1102 and so on...

Comment: I fear you will have to write your own parser to handle your specific syntax. Or use a configuration file with existing format (ini, yaml, json, etc)

Comment: `on '-c' .... like c1 goes to 1101, c2 goes to 1102 and so on` I do not understand. You want `test -c3 -t1101 -c2 -t1102 -c1 -t1103` ? Or maybe `test -c 3,1101 -c2,1102 -c1,1103`? What do the numbers mean?

Comment: @KamilCuk -  i want this - test -c 3 -t 1101 1102 1101?
These numbers are some test cases which i want to run depending on value of -c.

Comment: I've done this before [a _lot_] and I've done: `-t1101,1102,1103`. What about _multiple_ `-t`, such as: `-t1101 -t1102 -t1103`? Or, [both]: `-t1101,1102,1103 -t1104,1105 -t1106` which produces (e.g.) [effectively] `char **opt_t = { "1101", "1102", "1103", "1104", "1105", "1106", NULL };` or `int opt_t[] = { 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 0 };` Personally, I've never used `getopt`, preferring to "roll my own" because torturing `getopt` to do what a simple impl can do, hasn't been worth it for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CraigEstey... The solution exactly worked for me... Please make it an answer..